# Scrolling animation on UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, animation, uipickerview

I have an iPhone application with a UIPickerView with 6 components that displays numbers from 0 to 9.
I want to generate an animation that is similar to the slots machines (when each of the component scrolls for a few seconds and after it stops it display a random number)

Does anyone knows how to create this kind of animation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer at this post:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/01/longer-spinning-blurring.html

Good luck.

Comment: As of 2017-March-24 this blog is no longer available.